# 'NODE_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, windows, git-bash, path-variables

I'm on a windows 10 machine trying to run a build script from the git bash terminal.

On my terminal node is recognized just fine, for example I get the version when I run `node --version`.

But running the build script fails with the following error:

```
'NODE_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm guessing I need to add something to my PATH variables to get this to work, but what?

Comment: Could you show the build script you're trying to run?

Answer (score 60):

Use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package which easily sets environment variables.

### Step 1:

> Install cross-env from npm

```
npm i cross-env
```

In your package.json file (In this example your need is to run 'start' command which has 'NODE_OPTIONS')

```
{
    "name": "your-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS=<your options> <commands>",
    }
}
```

### Step 2

Add 'cross-env' in the script which you need to run NODE_OPTIONS. (In this case 'start' script)

```
{
    "name": "your-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=<your options> <commands>",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45):

For me installing the below mentioned package solved the problem

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works fine with default setup like next.js. Having to rewrite your package.json for different platforms (like the suggestion to use cross-env) is not an options for us.

Comment: working perfect for next.js and recommended to other for this solution.

Answer (score 15):

Not a PATH issue, NODE_OPTIONS is an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE that needs to be set before starting your build. To set en environment variable in Windows 10 you need to use the `set` command in a terminal mode. [See this article on SUPERUSER forum to learn more](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt/79614).

In your case, just add `set` before `NODE_OPTIONS` and that will fix your issue.

Here's how to integrate it in **package.json**:

```
...
"scripts": {
   ...
   "build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 && next build"
   ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to launch both the node process and the debugger via `F5`, which **does not require wrestling with env vars**.

Make sure `.vscode/launch.json` is deleted.

###### 1. Open the Run & Debug pane

[image: ctrl+shift+d]

###### 2. Click on Node.js

[image]

###### 3. DO NOT click on "Run script: dev" directly, instead click on the cog next to it

[image]

###### 4. Your `launch.json` should look similar to:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
       {
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "name": "Run Script: dev",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "yarn run dev",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```